# Does amazon provide an API for returning product information for a search term?

Tags: image-processing, search, search-engine, amazon-product-api

If you search on amazon for, say, "Don Quixote Spanish/English" you will find a number of matches or near-matches at http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Don%20Quixote%20Spanish%2FEnglish

You can then select any of them, and the URL will contain a designator (ASIN) for the product. For example, if you select a particular item in the result set, its URL might be:

[http://www.amazon.com/Don-Quixote-Spanish-English-Complete-ebook/dp/B00JQRGICM/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1405527063&sr=8-4&keywords=Don+Quixote+Spanish%2FEnglish](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JQRGICM)

The key piece of data here is the ASIN ("B00JQRGICM"); if you google using that alone, it will find many places where that product is referenced on the Internet.

My question is, does amazon provide an API whereby you can pass a search phrase (such as "Don Quixote Spanish/English") that will return to you an array of ASINs and other relevant data ("B00JQRGICM" and others)?

For example, I would like to call it something like this:

```
api/Books?SearchStr=Don Quixote Spanish/English
```

...and get back json such as:

```
{
Title: "Don Quixote in Spanish and English: Complete (Vol I & Vol II)"
Price: 16.15
ASIN: "B00JQRGICM"
Image: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/519dhx-MSOL._SL160_.jpg"
}
. . .
```

If there is such an API, has anybody here got experience in using it/sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can search Amazon and get an XML response with the ASINs using the `ListMatchingProducts` operation of the MWS Products API.
Here's the documentation with a sample request & response:
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_ListMatchingProducts.html

An easy way to test this is using the MWS Scratchpad: https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html